# How to boxplot full sample AND subsamples together in R?

Tags: r, boxplot

I have reading scores for 1 full sample and for 10 subsamples (gender(2) by race(5) = 10 combinations). I want to show all 11 boxplots together. The code below generates 10 boxplots but lacks the **full sample's** comparison boxplot.

How can I place all 11 boxplots together in same plot/graphic so they share a title, x-axis, y-axis, etc.?

Ideally, how can I place 10 subpopulation boxplots inside 1 maximum-width population boxplot that cuts across (is transparently layered over) all 10 subpopulation boxplots allowing viewer to graphically compare each subsample's 1Q, median, and 3Q to those of the full sample? (See below for example where red boxplot represents full sample of hs1$read (1Q: 44, median: 50, 3Q: 60).)

[image: Ideal Super-Boxplot]

Setup:

```
hs1 = read.table("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hs1.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
## ten boxplots (that i wish to combine with one more representing full sample)
boxplot( read ~ interaction(gender, race), data=hs1, las=2 )
```

Comment: Unclear question , how the full boxplot will share the same x-axis with the other boxplots?

Comment: @agstudy: See image for super-boxplot example. Alternatively, red boxplot (full sample) would be same width as other boxes and placed at far left or far right as part of the same series with other 10 boxplots with a label like "read" rather than 0.1, 1.1, etc. Also, note both examples share same title, x-axis, y-axis, etc.

Comment: I consider the offer of "bonus points" to be rather annoying. (I usually skip to the next question, but not today for some reason.)

Comment: @BondedDust: Thanks for your fantastic answer! I have changed "Bonus points" to "Ideally" as I realize I may have accidentally suggested an extra reward rather than suggesting that I would accept X but ideally would love Y. Apologies and thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
boxplot( read ~ interaction(gender, race), data=hs1, las=2 )
bxpfull <- boxplot( hs1$read, plot=FALSE)

 bxp(bxpfull, at= 5, add=TRUE, boxwex=18, 
      pars= list(boxcol="red",medcol="red", medbg="red", 
                 whiskcol="red", staplecol="red") )
```

[image]

If you wanted transparent colors (which not all graphics devices support) then this would give you a transparent pinkish result:

```
 bxp(bxpfull, at= 5, add=TRUE, boxwex=18, 
      pars= list(boxcol="#ff000050",medcol="#ff000050", medbg="#ff000050", 
                 whiskcol="#ff000050", staplecol="#ff000050") ,las=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If @BondedDust's fantastic answer generates the following defective graphic on your machine (note y-axis overlapping labels and non-transparent red boxplot) (due to your graphics device, R version, default packages, etc.), I tweaked that code to work on my machine as seen below.

[image: First Boxplot]

```
boxplot( read ~ interaction(gender, race), data=hs1, las=2 )
bxpfull <- boxplot( hs1$read, plot=FALSE)

bxp(bxpfull, at= 5.5, add=TRUE, boxwex=20, 
    pars= list(boxcol="red", boxfill= "transparent", medlty= "dashed", 
      medcol="red", medbg="red", axes= FALSE, whiskcol="red", staplecol="red") )
```

Note below that y-axis is fixed and red boxplot is transparent. Additionally, dashed line allows view of median 0.3 and red boxplot is centered and stretched accurately.

[image: Updated Boxplot]